# Kriging variance results

Tags: variance, interpolation, kriging, heatmap

I'm quite a newb at statistics and interpolation, and I cannot understand how to interpret the error estimation computed by Kriging.

For example, I performed kriging on temperature values (Celsius degrees) and I plotted this heatmap with the error estimation results, which I understand is kriging variance (right?).
[image]

What I get is that this error estimation gives a measure of the reliability of the model and that the blue/light blue areas are the best estimated ones. In fact, the blue areas correspond to the coordinates of the sensor nodes I considered.
However, what I don't get, is how this variance is computed and therefore what it actually represents: the yellow areas are worse than the blue ones regarding what?

Answer (score 1):

In ordinary kriging, the variance does not depend on the measurements but only on their location. So it is merely a measure of how far you are from a measurement location. It is not higher in areas surrounded by diverging/contrasted measurements as someone would expect. This property is discussed in

Heuvelink, et al. (2002). *Is the ordinary kriging variance a proper measure of interpolation error?*